# RewriteRule with URL parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When using the rule

```
RewriteRule blah test.php?id=12345 [L]
```

then accessing `blah?hello=1` is rewritten into `test.php?id=12345`, and the `hello=1` parameter is lost.

How to have:

```
blah                     => test.php?id=12345
blah?hello=1             => test.php?id=12345&hello=1
blah?hello=1&youhou=2    => test.php?id=12345&hello=1&youhou=2
```

instead?

Comment: Just use the QSA flag (`[L]` => `[L,QSA]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the solution is to use the 
[QSA flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) (Query String Append):

```
RewriteRule blah test.php?id=12345 [L,QSA]
```